# Master playlist generate points to only one resolution among multiple

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i video.mp4 -master_pl_name master.m3u8    ^
  -vf scale=w=640:h=-2 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4   -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\360p_%%03d.ts  D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\360p_%v.m3u8 ^
  -vf scale=w=842:h=-2 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4  -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\480p_%%03d.ts  D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\480p_%v.m3u8 ^
  -vf scale=w=1280:h=-2 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4  -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\720p_%%03d.ts  D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\720p_%v.m3u8 ^
  -vf scale=w=1920:h=-2 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4  -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\1080p_%%03d.ts  D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\1080p_%v.m3u8
```

It include only the 360p resolution playlist link .

Comment: Next time asking a question, please include the full command line output as well, and, *ask* a question rather than just posting a bit of code. Also, please don't ask the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: I'm sorry . It was an honest mistake . Coming to the output , the outputs are in the form of file . And my question description basically defines whats going wrong .

Answer (score 1):

Your existing command invokes 4 HLS muxers. For generating HLS output with multiple audio/video renditions, you have to invoke one HLS muxer, map all streams multiple times (once for each rendition), and set `var_stream_map` to group these streams into individual renditions.

Basic form is

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i video.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 ^
  -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000 ^
  -filter:v:0 scale=w=640:h=-2  -maxrate:v:0 856k  -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k  ^
  -filter:v:1 scale=w=842:h=-2  -maxrate:v:1 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k ^
  -filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=-2 -maxrate:v:2 2996k -bufsize:v:2 4200k -b:a:2 128k ^
  -filter:v:3 scale=w=1920:h=-2 -maxrate:v:3 5350k -bufsize:v:3 7500k -b:a:3 192k ^
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" -hls_time 4 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 ^
  -hls_segment_filename D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\seg_%v_%03d.ts D:\xampp\htdocs\streaming-demo\pl_%v.m3u8
```

You may need to escape the `%` if you're running this from within a DOS batch file.

Comment: It is working . But gives me error in the filter . ```Only '-vf scale=w=640:h=-2' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters```

Comment: That's a logging [bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7712). Can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much Gyan ! It is working very well like intended . I couldn't thank you enough.

Comment: The answer would be more useful if it explained what the OP did wrong and what was used to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, OP posted this as a bug report at trac and I provided the conceptual answer there. Will add it here.